# What's the meaning of .js file of the form "define([...], function(...) {...});"

Tags: javascript

I have .js files of the following form:

```
define([
   'jquery',
  'backbone'
], function($, Backbone) {
  // function stuff here
}
```

What's the purpose of writing the file that way? Is it some convention to define it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're using the CommonJS AMD-style definitions to register modules.

Info: http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/11/04/requirejsamd-module-forms/

The first argument is the module dependencies, and the second is the module itself.